# increment the result of PHP MySQL query by number

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am currently using the following code in a WordPress site's functions.php file to display a petition signatory counter on the front-end of the website and it's working fine:

```
// Add shortcode for GravityForms Petition Form counter
function set_gf_petition_counter_num(){
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#gf_petition_signed_counter span').text('<?php
$summary = RGFormsModel::get_form_counts(1);
echo "".$summary['total']."";
?>');
    });
    </script> 

<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'set_gf_petition_counter_num' );
```

The issue is that the form submissions are counting at zero because I've only just implemented this form after switching the site from ***Contact Form 7*** to ***GravityForms***.

There's already 127 entries from the old CF7 form and none of these are stored in the database.

It replaces the `<span>0</span>` in the body paragraph `id="gf_petition_signed_counter"` with the number returned by using `get_form_counts(1)` to check for the *"entries"* count in GravityForms (`1` being the form ID).

How can I increment the number of GF subsmissions it returns by 127 so I have the true number of submissions?

Comment: Can't you just do `$summary['total'] += 127`?

Comment: Thanks.  I had to enclose it in brackets, but it is working.  Can you change the comment to an answer to I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to increment the total directly after retrieving the number of forms:

```
$summary = RGFormsModel::get_form_counts(1);
$summary['total'] += 127;
echo "".$summary['total']."";
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I actually implemented by using `echo "".($summary['total'] += 127)."";`.  Is there any downside to doing it this way instead of your suggestion?